# Web Forms For Marketers Drop Down List Items Do Appear on Chinese Version fo Site

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2, web-forms-for-marketers

I have a Sitecore site with English and Chinese versions of items. For some reason, drop down lists do not populate on the Chinese versions of the form. The form is definitely published.

Comment: Are the items filling the drop down published in the Chinese language?

Comment: I think so. Its a little hard to tell. There is no language indicator on the form where you enter drop down list items.